# How to use ros::pluginlib to load multi-library

Tags: ros

I am trying to use `ros::pluginlib` to load a plugin called A_Plugin which has been registered to ROS Package System correctly. One thing to note is that A_Plugin depends on `Opensplice DDS`, and it need to link the DDS libraries "`libddskernel.so`" ,"`libdcpsisocpp.so`". In `CmakeLists.txt` file, I write like this:
```

```
add_library(A_Plugin
  src/aplugin.cpp
)
target_link_libraries(A_Plugin
  $ENV{OSPL_HOME}/lib/libddskernel.so
  $ENV{OSPL_HOME}/lib/libdcpsisocpp.so
)
```

```
It can be registered to ROS package system correctly, but when I use pluginlib::ClassLoader to load A_plugin, I got the following `errors:terminate` called after throwing an instance of `'pluginlib::CreateClassException'what():`  MultiLibraryClassLoader: Could not create object of class type test::A_Plugin as no factory exists for it. Make sure that the library exists and was explicitly loaded through `MultiLibraryClassLoader::loadLibrary()`. How can I solve this problem? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, turns out I was missing the plugin class declaration in the *.cpp file. I included it and it worked fine. The declaration should be something like:
`PLUGINLIB_DECLARE_CLASS(rqt_example_cpp, MyPlugin, rqt_example_cpp::MyPlugin, rqt_gui_cpp::Plugin)`

This can be seen in the example from the rqt tutorial github repo, line 62:
https://github.com/lucasw/rqt_mypkg/blob/master/rqt_example_cpp/src/rqt_example_cpp/my_plugin.cpp